# Регулярное выражение: 10 символов и два символа не буквы

Tags: javascript, php, регулярные-выражения, angularjs

Помогите составить регулярку. Нужно, чтобы в строке можно было ввести минимум 10 символов, из которых как минимум 2 не буквы. Составил регулярку, но символы, которые не должны быть буквами идут подряд и только тогда проходят проверку, а мне нужно, чтобы во всей строке два символа - это не буквы.

`^.*[^a-zA-Z]{2,}.*$`

Проверил на этом сайте `https://regex101.com/`

Comment: Тогда поправьте для красивости - ^(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2}).{10,}$ - https://regex101.com/r/2uKi9Z/1

Comment: `(?=.{10,}$)([A-Za-z]{0,}[^A-Za-z\n ]{1}[A-Za-z]{0,}[^A-Za-z\n ]{1}[A-Za-z]{0,})*` более 10 символов более 2 не букв.

Comment: В общем, используйте `^(?=.{10})(?:[a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z]){2}.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
^(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2}).{10}
```

Comment: Подходит первый ответ, который удалили.

`^(?=.{10,})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2,}).*$`

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.{10,})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2,}).*$

(?=.{10,}) - минимум 10 символов
(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2,}) -  как минимум дважды встречаются не буквы в произвольном месте
```

Update

```
^(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2}).{10,}$

^(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2}) - проверяем, что дважды встречаются не буквы 
.{10,}$ - и что строка содержит не менее 10 символов
```

Comment: А зачем удалил? Вон автор пишет, что ему твой ответ подошёл.

Comment: Да я подумал, что надо упростить, а был уже не за компом

Comment: О, почти до моего упростил)

Comment: а вариантов то не так много :)